# Autoload Audio Issues on Web Browser

Tags: google-chrome, html5-audio, autoload, autoplay

**Problem Script 1: Can autoload on browser but refresh the page auto load audio is not working. If press to the button inside the page, the autoload audio will be function.
**

```
<script>
    var sound = new Howl({
       src: ['./audio/xwl_bg.mp3'],
       autoplay: true,
       loop: true,
       volume: 0.5,
    });
sound.play();
</script>
```

**Problem Script 2: This is a press button function to play the audio.

HTML:**

```
div class="wrapper">
   <div class="block">
       <div class="player-btn">
         <div class="player-btn-particles"></div>
    </div>
    <audio id="track" class="svg-play" src="audio/xwl_bg.mp3"> 
        <source src="audio/xwl_bg.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" autoplay="true" type="audio" loop="true">
    </audio>
    </div>
                        
    <!-- Filter -->
    <svg class="svg-hidden" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
    <defs>
       <filter id="fancy-goo">
           <feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="10" result="blur" />
           <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="2 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
           <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    </svg>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
<script>
     let btn = document.getElementsByClassName('player-btn')[0],
     icon = document.getElementsByClassName('svg-play')[0];
     
     let audio = document.getElementById('track'),
     isPlaying = false;

     btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    e.target.classList.toggle('active');
    if (!icon.classList.contains('to-pause')) {
        icon.classList.add('to-pause');
    } else {
       icon.classList.remove('to-pause');
       icon.classList.add('to-play');
    }
    if (isPlaying) {
         audio.pause();
         isPlaying = false;
    } else {
         audio.play();
         isPlaying = true;
        }
    });
</script>
```

Now, I need some help and advise me how to combine together with this two scripts be one. And user can control audio loading.

I try to modify the script before. When I combine script 1 to script 2, the button is stop function.